# Explain this quote from Lord Byron

Tags: poetry

I can relate to what it says, I feel, but I don't quite understand it - does that make sense? Probably not. My first language is not English, so the confusion is great!

How would you interpret this in plain English:

> As long as I retain my feeling and my passion for Nature, I can partly
>   soften or subdue my other passions and resist or endure those of
>   others.

Comment: I think even English speakers need context to understand this quote.

Comment: What do you think it means?

Comment: To add context: *... and within these few years, when I have endeavoured at better things and written what I suspect to have the principle of duration in it, the Church, the Chancellor, and all men ... have risen up against me and my later publications. ...  It is lucky that I am of a temper not to be easily turned aside though by no means difficult to irritate. ...*

Comment: Context continued: *I write to you from the Villa Dupuy, near Leghorn, with the islands of Elba and Corsica visible from my balcony, and my old friend the Mediterranean rolling blue at my feet. As long as I retain my feeling and my passion for Nature, I can partly soften or subdue my other passions and resist or endure those of others.*

Comment: He means that when he has the urge to hop into bed with the milk maid, he can go bird watching instead, and this works fine for him.  We call this a noble sentiment.

Comment: @Greg: actually, from the full quote, what he is resisting appears to be the temptation to kill all his critics (I believe a very common temptation for writers). I don't know whether Lord Byron refrained from hopping into bed with milkmaids.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. That helped me out a lot :-). I cannot up any of them as I only have one post, sorry. @GregLee excellent way of explaining it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the poet is trying to emphasize the importance of being connected to the nature as it helps him to keep his other passions at bay. I think the passions he is referring to are the materialistic desires of the world which can often be corrupting in nature. He also mentions that these passions can also be corrupting in a similar manner, even when they belong to other people, and the poet is subjected to them, directly or indirectly.

As English is also not my native tongue, I might be wrong in my inference. Hope this helps. Any corrections are welcome.

P.S.- Remember Me and Epitaph to a Dog are amazing poems by Lord Byron! :-)

Comment: I believe you are correct; altho I might've misinterpreted it in regards to the "being connected to nature" bit. Nature's awesome, but I'll be inside for now. Thank you